# Finding euclidean distance between all pair of points

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have 8 points in a list and I need to calculate euclidean distance between all possible pairs. I could write a for loop and go on calculating the distance but is there a better approach / method available with python / numpy / others?

Coordinates points:

```
x1,y1 , x2,y2, x3,y3, .... .. ,, .. ,xn,yn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`euclidean_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) from sklearn. Usage (from the manual)

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
>>> X = [[0, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> # distance between rows of X
>>> euclidean_distances(X, X)
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 0.]])
>>> # get distance to origin
>>> euclidean_distances(X, [[0, 0]])
array([[1.        ],
       [1.41421356]])
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's happening?

Comment: The documentation page pretty much says it all. What in particular are you confused about?